# Restart-service WinRM remotely without yes/no

Tags: powershell, powercli

How can I `Restart-service` remotely with WinRM, without a yes/no confirmation on a remote computer in a workgroup?

Comment: Please, show at least one line of code you have tried ?

Comment: Have you tried `Invoke-Command` with a `-ComputerName` parameter, and the `-Force` and `-Confirm` parameters for `Restart-Service` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI:

```
$ServiceName = 'Spooler'
$WMI = Get-WmiObject win32_service -Filter "name='$ServiceName'" -ComputerName $computer
$WMI.StopService()
$WMI.StartService()
```